# code in the middle is different, everything else the same

Tags: oop, design-patterns, inheritance, refactoring, polymorphism

I often have a situation where I need to do:

```
function a1() {
 a = getA;
 b = getB;
 b.doStuff();
 ....  // do some things
 b.send()
 return a - b;
}

function a2() {
 a = getA;
 b = getB;
 b.doStuff();
 ....  // do some things, but different to above
 b.send()
 return a - b;
}
```

I feel like I am repeating myself, yet where I have `....`, the methods are different, have different signatures, etc..

What do people normally do? Add an if (this type) do this stuff, else do the other stuff that is different? It doesn't seem like a very good solution either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Polymorphism](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/books/OOP_Polymorphism.aspx) and possibly abstraction and encapsulation are your friends here.

You should specify better what kind of instructions you have on the `....  // do some things` part. If you're always using the same information, but doing different things with it, the solution is fairly easy using simple polymorphism. See my first revision of this answer. I'll assume you need different information to do the specific tasks in each case.

You also didn't specify if those functions are in the same class/module or not. If they are not, you can use inheritance to share the common parts and polymorphism to introduce different behavior in the specific part. If they are in the same class you don't need inheritance nor polymorphism.

---

**In different classes**

Taking into account you're stating in the question that you might need to make calls to functions with different signature depending on the implementation subclass (for instance, passing `a` or `b` as parameter depending on the case), and assuming you need to do something with the intermediate local variables (i.e. `a` and `b`) in the specific implementations:

*Short version*: Polymorphism+Encapsulation: Pass all the possible *in & out* parameters that every subclass might need to the abstract function. Might be less painful if you encapsulate them in an object.

*Long Version*
I'd store intermediate state in  generic class' member, and pass it to the implementation methods. Alternatively you could grab the State from the implementation methods instead of passing it as an argument. Then, you can make two subclasses of it implementing the `doSpecificStuff(State)` method, and grabbing the needed parameters from the intermediate state in the superclass. If needed by the superclass, subclasses might also modify state.

(Java specifics next, sorry)

```
public abstract class Generic {
  private State state = new State();
  public void a() {
     preProcess();
     prepareState();
     doSpecificStuf(state);
     clearState();
     return postProcess();
  }
  protected void preProcess(){ 
     a = getA;
     b = getB;
     b.doStuff();
  }
  protected Object postProcess(){ 
     b.send()
     return a - b;
  }
  protected void prepareState(){ 
     state.prepareState(a,b);
  }
  private void clearState() { 
     state.clear();
  }
  protected abstract doSpecificStuf(State state);
}
public class Specific extends Generic { 
   protected doSpecificStuf(State state) { 
       state.getA().doThings();
       state.setB(someCalculation);
   }
}
public class Specific2 extends Generic { 
   protected doSpecificStuf(State state) { 
       state.getB().doThings();
   }
}
```

---

**In the same class**

Another possibility would be making the `preProcess()` method return a `State` variable, and  use it inthe  implementations of `a1()` and `a2()`.

```
public class MyClass {
  protected State preProcess(){ 
     a = getA;
     b = getB;
     b.doStuff();
     return new State(a,b);
  }
  protected Object postProcess(){ 
     b.send()
     return a - b;
  }
  public void a1(){
      State st = preProcess();
      st.getA().doThings();
      State.clear(st);
      return postProcess();
  }
  public void a2(){
      State st = preProcess();
      st.getB().doThings();
      State.clear(st);
      return postProcess();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, [don't repeat yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). My golden rule (which admittedly I break from time on time) is based on the [ZOI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_One_Infinity) rule: all code must live exactly zero, one or infinite times. If you see code repeated, you should refactor that into a common ancestor.

That said, it is not possible to give you a definite answer how to refactor your code; there are infinite ways to do this. For example, if `a1()` and `a2()` reside in different classes then you can use polymorphism. If they live in the same class, you can create a function that receives an anonymous function as parameter and then `a1()` and `a2()` are just wrappers to that function. Using a (shudder) parameter to change the function behavior can be used, too.

Comment: Good point, but the OP is talking about having to use methods with different signatures. How is the common part supposed to know which parameters to pass to this anonymous function? What happens if those parameters are local variables to the common part?

Comment: @XaviLópez - the common part doesn't need to know anything. The (say) `a_common()` function receives everything already chewed when it's called by `a1()` or `a2()`. But this is largely speculative, since we don't have any code.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "receives everything already chewed". However, I do agree with you regarding that it is very unlikely that this question will get any progress without the OP adding a little more context.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this in one of 2 ways. Both `a1` and `a2` will call `a3`. `a3` will do the shared code, and:
1. call a function that it receives as a parameter, which does either the middle part of `a1` or the middle part of `a2` (and they will pass the correct parameter),
- or -
2. receive a flag (e.g. boolean), which will tell it which part it needs to do, and using an if statement will execute the correct code.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "and they will pass the correct parameter" part? What happens if the parameter to be passed is a local variable defined in the common part?

Comment: @XaviLópez: In most modern languages, you can create objects of type `Function`, and pass them as parameters. So for example in `a1`, you would create such an object that does the content of the original `a1`, and pass this object as a parameter.

Comment: I get your point, Eran, but then again, what if the function `a1()` you pass needs local variable of `a_common()` `x` and in another instance, the function `a2()` you pass needs local variable `y` of `a_common()`. How do you know in `a_common()` if you have to pass `x` or `y` as an argument to the function you receive? You would still have to encapsulate all possible variables in an object and use it as argument to `a1()` and `a2()`.

Comment: @XaviLópez: Then pass both. Call both `a1()` and `a2()` with `a` and `b` (the only locals declared in the common part). I do agree, however, that this is a potentially bad thing, if there will be too many local variables. In that case, maybe the 2nd option should be preferred...

Answer (score 0):

This screams out loud for the design pattern "Template Method"

The general part is in the super class:

```
package patterns.templatemethod;

public abstract class AbstractSuper {

public Integer doTheStuff(Integer a, Integer b) {
    Integer x = b.intValue() + a.intValue();

    Integer y = doSpecificStuff(x);

    return b.intValue() * y;
}

protected abstract Integer doSpecificStuff(Integer x);
}
```

The spezific part is in the subclass:

```
package patterns.templatemethod;

public class ConcreteA extends AbstractSuper {

@Override
protected Integer doSpecificStuff(Integer x) {
    return x.intValue() * x.intValue();
}

}
```

For every spezific solution you implement a subclass, with the specific behavior.

If you put them all in an Collection, you can iterate over them and call always the common method and evry class does it's magic. ;)

hope this helps

Comment: The OP is saying in the question that the methods can even have different signature, and need different kinds of information. Maybe in one case he wants to do `doSpecificStuff(a)` and in others `a = doSpecificStuff(b)`.

Comment: @XaviLópez: If everything before ist the same, he can hand over all variables to the template method. So he can access all values available and do in the method whatever he needs. So this requirement is no show stopper. If you need more data you have to retrieve it from elsewhere (e.g. DB, files, in memory data model, ...).

Comment: That's precisely what I've been suggesting in my answer. Passing all possible variables that the template method might use in all its implementations. Encapsulating them might be a good choice.